# Regex to extract string between two slashes and a specified string in it

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have as string like this /test/xychcm_prd/test/ss or /test/xychcmss_trn/test/ss. I want extract the string **xychcm_prd** or **xychcmss_trn** from it. Here _prd or _tst is predefined. The string is always between slashes. How do get this string using regex?

Comment: This is basic regex and can be learned by a quick google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex to found your string:

```
[^\/]*(?:_prd|_trn)
```

The `[^/]*` will take every character before the **_trn** or **_prd** except the slash and will stop at it.

The `(_prd|_trn)` will make the regex to search for **_trn** or **_prd** at the end of the string you want.

The `?:` will make a non-capturing group from the `(_prd|_trn)` since you don't need it.

[Live exemple](https://regex101.com/r/Mvk5GE/2)

Comment: Looks as though the non-capturing group is still returning. Perhaps `[^\/]*(?=_prd|_trn)` ?

Comment: a non-capturing group will return the information. But will not create a group usable.